# When merging runs A,B in Timsort (in function merge_lo) it says "Must also have that ssa.keys[na-1] belongs at the end of the merge". Why?

Tags: timsort

A and B are adjacent runs on a stack, with A being the bottom and smaller run(If B were smaller merge_hi would be performing the merging but the same question applies there as well).I have been trying to figure why the last element of A MUST be bigger than the last element of B because I don't see how the run decomposition (or the rest of the algorithm) would ensure that condition. Also, in the same function the code seems to suggest that the first element of B is always smaller than the first element of A which I also don't understand why, but I'm guessing the answer to this question is tied to the answer of the first question.

Answer (score 0):

In short, galloping is the reason. That's why we haven't seen it at first, because I thought `gallop_`{`left`,`right`} is called only from `merge`_{`lo`,`hi`}. But it isn't true. `gallop_`... are also called from `merge_at`, *before* `merge`_{`lo`,`hi`} are called, in order to find "Where does b start in a?" and "Where does a end in b?". Those calls (and subsequent code) *change* `ssb` (and its length `nb`), and also `ssa` and its length `na`, such that the invariant in the title is satisfied.

That is, the point is that A and B are **not** "adjacent runs on the runstack" as found in the original list to be sorted. Before calling `merge`_{`lo`,`hi`}, they are trimmed so that the condition in the title holds. That is, prior to A being merged with B, the elements of B greater than the last element of A are [explicitly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f8b534477a2a51d85ea1663530f685f805f2b247/Objects/listobject.c#L1922) left out of consideration. In other words, "Must also have that `ssa.keys[na-1]` belongs at the end of the merge" is true not because of some special property of `ssa.keys[na-1]`, but because we have defined "the end of the merge" in such a way. :-)

That also means that when you implement Timsort yourself, and you leave out the galloping, you must also leave out that optimization being talked about here, otherwise the code won't work right.